# Java Spring - how to handle missing required request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Consider the following mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/superDuperPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String superDuperPage(@RequestParam(value = "someParameter", required = true) String parameter)
{
    return "somePage";
}
```

I want to handle the missing parameter case by **not** adding in `required = false`. By default, `400` error is returned, but I want to return, let's say, a different page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If a required `@RequestParam` is not present in the request, Spring will throw a [`MissingServletRequestParameterException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MissingServletRequestParameterException.html) exception. You can define an `@ExceptionHandler` in the same controller or in a `@ControllerAdvice` to handle that exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
public void handleMissingParams(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex) {
    String name = ex.getParameterName();
    System.out.println(name + " parameter is missing");
    // Actual exception handling
}
```

> I want to return let's say a different page. How to I achieve this?

As the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) states:

> Much like standard controller methods annotated with a `@RequestMapping`
>   annotation, **the method arguments and return values of
>   `@ExceptionHandler` methods can be flexible**. For example, the
>   `HttpServletRequest` can be accessed in Servlet environments and the
>   `PortletRequest` in Portlet environments. **The return type can be a
>   `String`, which is interpreted as a view name**, a `ModelAndView` object, a
>   `ResponseEntity`, or you can also add the `@ResponseBody` to have the
>   method return value converted with message converters and written to
>   the response stream.

Comment: @Ali this worked perfectly. thank you for your help. Also, is there a way of knowing which method threw this exception? I can't find it in `printStack()`.

Comment: @peech The exception only encapsulates param type and param name information. So No, you can't know what method throws the exception.

Comment: @AliDehghani How to find the parameter names in case of multiple parameters missing?

Answer (score 22):

An alternative

If you use the **@ControllerAdvice** on your class and if it extends the Spring base class **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler**. A pre-defined function has been created on the base class for this purpose. You have to override it in your handler.

```
    @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    String name = ex.getParameterName();
    logger.error(name + " parameter is missing");

    return super.handleMissingServletRequestParameter(ex, headers, status, request);
}
```

This base class is very useful, especially if you want to process the validation errors that the framework creates.

Comment: More verbose explanations and examples about @ContollerAdvice can be found in https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Comment: This worked for me. The accepted answer did not work as I was getting "Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for..."

Comment: this approach is no longer valid for sprinboot 3 /spring 6. The method handleMissingServletRequestParameter is not overridable anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with **Spring 4.1** onwards and **Java 8** by leveraging the **Optional** type. In your example that would mean your **@RequestParam** `String` will have now type of `Optional<String>`.

[Take a look at this article](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/Spring41-and-Java8-Optional-as-RequestParam-RequestHeader-MatrixVariable.html) for an example showcasing this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue today (30/08/2023) using Spring 3.1.3. You can solve this issue by overriding the protected function `handleMissingServletRequestParameter` of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` base class.

```kotlin
@ControllerAdvice
class DevBlogExceptionHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {

    override fun handleMissingServletRequestParameter(
        ex: MissingServletRequestParameterException,
        headers: HttpHeaders,
        status: HttpStatusCode,
        request: WebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Any>? {

        val errorMessages = listOf("Required query parameter \"${ex.parameterName}\" is missing")

        val error = DevBlogException(
            status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            errors = errorMessages,
            timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now(),
            statusCode = status.value()
        )

        return ResponseEntity<Any>(error, error.status);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not that relevant, but I came across to a similar need: change the 5xx error to 4xx error for authentication header missing.

The controller is as follows:

```java
@RequestMapping("list")
public ResponseEntity<Object> queryXXX(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token) {
...
}
```

When you cURL it without the authorization header you get a 5xx error:

```
curl --head -X GET "http://localhost:8081/list?xxx=yyy" -H "accept: */*"

HTTP/1.1 500
...
```

To change it to 401 you can

```java
@ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> authMissing(org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        return IResponse.builder().code(401).message(ex.getMessage()).data(null).build();
}


@Data
public class IResponse<T> implements Serializable {
    private Integer code;
    private String message = "";
    private T data;
...
}
```

You can verify it by an automation test:

```java
@Test
void testQueryEventListWithoutAuthentication() throws Exception {
    val request = get("/list?enrollEndTime=1619176774&enrollStartTime=1619176774&eventEndTime=1619176774&eventStartTime=1619176774");
    mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
}
```